# What is "mains outlet tester" (for proper wiring) in the context of US power connector standard?

Tags: connector, mains, wiring, tools, test-equipment

I'm curious about this [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214409/got-shocked-by-a-native-dell-laptop-charger-outputting-19-5-v-6-5-a-dc-it-was-r#comment456673_214409). It says what

> ... in the US or UK you should be able to go to a hardware store and buy
>   an outlet tester for very little money. This is a little plastic
>   housing which plugs into a wall socket and has 3 LEDs. The pattern of
>   which LED lights up will tell you if your wall socket is properly
>   wired.

But North American standard power connector isn't grounded, so 3 LEDs looks too many for me. Moreover, there is Japanese version of this connector which is polarity-agnostic even!

What is "mains outlet tester" (for proper wiring) in the context of US power connector standard? What extra LED indicates? Am I correct assuming what Japanese outlets are not testable at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a picture that shows what is tested with a USA outlet tester. Since about 1960, USA 120 V outlets have been required to have a third pin for earth ground. The neutral is also grounded but only at the distribution panel and at the service entrance.

This tester will not indicate a condition where the ground pin is connected to the neutral inside the outlet. I have seen an installation where all of the outlets were wired that way. The date of the installation was about 1962.

I believe that there was a time when outlet boxes were not required to be grounded in the USA. In that case, the cover-plate screw will not be grounded.

[image]

Here is a neon test light that can be used for two-prong receptacles. Note that the old extension cord is not polarized. I believe that there was a time when wall receptacles were not polarized in the USA.

[image]

Here is how a neon test light can be used to identify the hot slot when there is no ground available. The neon light draws only about 300 microamps with a solid connection and much less using a person's body as an antenna.

[image]

Comment: So you no longer have to deal with non-grounded sockets? (which are mechanically incompatible with this tester)

Comment: There are still plenty of non-grounded receptacles around. There are adapters that allow 3-prong plugs to be used. They have a tab or lead that can be attached to the cover-plate screw that may or may not be grounded.

Comment: Regarding your last addition with Japanese-style non-polarized socket: what can you tell about proper wiring of such socket as result of testing besides obvious wired or not wired?

Comment: Energized or not-energized is all you can tell. You could also check to see if the cover-plate screw is grounded, but not the quality of the ground connection. If you were to replace the receptacle with a polarized one, it would tell you which wire is hot. In the USA, any broken non-polarized receptacle would need to be replaced by a polarized one. The non-polarized socket pictured is an old USA socket, not Japanese, but they may be the same.

Comment: Thank you, now its clear what can be tested about legacy sockets