# Why is there earthing (the neon bulb on the tester glows faintly) on Hi-Link PM01's output or another AC-DC wall adapter?

Tags: power-electronics, ac-dc

I have a 5V relay circuit to power from AC using Hi-Link 5v/3w PM-01 module, however when i tested with a tester (neon bulb type) there is  indication of earthing (neon blub glows brightly) I have read related questions in this forum, and tested my existing wall/ laptop adapters as well to exhibit the same.

I understand that there is a capacitor between AC neutral - DC negative terminal.

What can be done to remove this AC leak or make it insignificant for the DC circuit? and does this have an chance of failing my device. As a designer, what would be the aspect regarding this condition?

So far I have used a quick blow fuse only in the AC end, and planning to add a varistor as well (ordered some varistors.)

Update:
After connecting the DC load, the AC leak in DC output is reduced to the point where the neon tester doesn't glow at all.

Comment: How bright does it glow???   Those things are so sensitive they can glow from just capacitive connections (i.e. no actual metal-to-metal connection to ground.. the wires just have to be 'close')   If it's super dim, you might be fooling yourself.    Have you searched for this 'short' using a standard ohmmeter????

Comment: A neon tester can glow with just the capacitance of a person't body as a ground. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214535/what-is-mains-outlet-tester-for-proper-wiring-in-the-context-of-us-power-con